# What is the best approach to create an embossed pattern on a non typical mesh?

Tags: modeling, retopology

I want to create a pattern on the blue part of the razor blade. But I am kind of stuck as I spent 3 hours to recreate it manually by retopology. Any suggestion for a better approach?
Thanks a lot!
[image]

Comment: can't you just fake it with a height map?

Comment: fusion360 ...my tip for this.